# Django Celery & Django-Celery-Beat

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I'm new to asynchronous tasks and I'm using django-celery and was hoping to use django-celery-beat to schedule periodic tasks.

However it looks like celery-beat doesn't pick up one-off tasks. Do I need two Celery instances, one as a worker for one off tasks and one as beat for scheduled tasks for this to work?

Comment: There is no need for two separate celery workers for beat to work properly. Can you share the celery, beat settings and config files.

Comment: Yeah, I know I only need one worker for beat– but I also have a way for users to trigger one-off functions that aren't part of a schedule and are executed. Both can be done from one beat worker? I'm using this command:

Comment: "celery -A myproject.celery beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler"

Comment: This is what I use for the one off tasks: "celery -A flock.celery worker -l DEBUG -E" @Jijo

Comment: No need of 2 separate celery instance. Both scheduled and non scheduled task can be executed in one instance. You can specify the queue name while defining the periodic task.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `-B` parameter to your worker, it is a parameter to run beat schedule. This worker will do all other tasks, the ones sent from beat, and the "one-off" ones, it really doesn't matter for worker.

So the full command looks like:

`celery -A flock.celery worker -l DEBUG -BE`.

Comment: -B does not work on windows, and you DO need a separate instance

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple periodic tasks executing for example every 10 seconds, then they should all point to the same schedule object. please refer [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-beat/)

Comment: The question was about mixing one-off tasks with periodic tasks, not multiple periodic tasks.